# Why is my term query not working?

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is my settings file -

```
{
    "settings": {
        "mappings": {
            "default": {
                "properties": {
                    "AIRPORT_CODE": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "PROVINCE_NAME": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "AIRPORT_NAME": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "CITY_NAME": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "TYPE": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "COUNTRY_NAME": {
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are 2 documents that I ingested into the index -

**Document - 1**

```
{
  "AIRPORT_CODE": "SQA",
  "PROVINCE_NAME": "California",
  "AIRPORT_NAME": "Santa Ynez Airport",
  "CITY_NAME": "SANTA YNEZ",
  "TYPE": "AIRPORT"
}
```

**Document - 2**

```
{
  "PROVINCE_NAME": "SANTIAGO",
  "CITY_NAME": "SANTIAGO",
  "COUNTRY_NAME": "DOMINICAN REPUBLIC",
  "TYPE": "HOTEL"
}
```

Here is my search query -

```
{
    "size": 4,
    "timeout": "2m",
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "SQA"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "filter": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "TYPE": "AIRPORT"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "explain": false
}
```

The "TYPE" field has been defined as keyword. But the above query doesn't return anything. If change the "TYPE" value from "AIRPORT" to "airport" (lowercase), I get the results back. What am I doing wrong?

Note # My effort is to get this query working so I can take the advantage of filter cache (node query cache).

Thanks in advance!

Update - 1: adding out of GET index/_mapping

```
{
  "rc-filter-cache": {
    "mappings": {
      "default": {
        "properties": {
          "AIRPORT_CODE": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "AIRPORT_NAME": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "CITY_NAME": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "COUNTRY_NAME": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "PROVINCE_NAME": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "TYPE": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "settings": {
            "properties": {
              "index": {
                "properties": {
                  "analysis": {
                    "properties": {
                      "analyzer": {
                        "properties": {
                          "keylower": {
                            "properties": {
                              "tokenizer": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                  "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "mappings": {
                "properties": {
                  "default": {
                    "properties": {
                      "properties": {
                        "properties": {
                          "AIRPORT_CODE": {
                            "properties": {
                              "type": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                  "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          "AIRPORT_NAME": {
                            "properties": {
                              "type": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                  "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          "CITY_NAME": {
                            "properties": {
                              "type": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                  "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          "COUNTRY_NAME": {
                            "properties": {
                              "type": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                  "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          "PROVINCE_NAME": {
                            "properties": {
                              "type": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                  "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          "TYPE": {
                            "properties": {
                              "analyzer": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                  "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                  }
                                }
                              },
                              "type": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                  "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you check what GET index/_mapping gives? I'm sure you have a default mapping here with a text field.

Comment: I added an update to the post, showing output of _mapping.

Comment: @jagamot you are saying that TYPE is a keyword but your mapping shows that TYPE is a text (there is another field TYPE.keyword which is a keyword) so, in your query just replace TYPE with TYPE.keyword

Comment: The mapping you shared clearly shows that your field is not mapped as you think. And you have a default mapping here.

Comment: What tells you it is not picking my mapping for the TYPE field?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to solve that:

```
DELETE index
PUT index
{
  "mappings": {
    "default": {
      "properties": {
        "AIRPORT_CODE": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "PROVINCE_NAME": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "AIRPORT_NAME": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "CITY_NAME": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "TYPE": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "COUNTRY_NAME": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
PUT index/default/1
{
  "AIRPORT_CODE": "SQA",
  "PROVINCE_NAME": "California",
  "AIRPORT_NAME": "Santa Ynez Airport",
  "CITY_NAME": "SANTA YNEZ",
  "TYPE": "AIRPORT"
}
PUT index/default/2
{
  "PROVINCE_NAME": "SANTIAGO",
  "CITY_NAME": "SANTIAGO",
  "COUNTRY_NAME": "DOMINICAN REPUBLIC",
  "TYPE": "HOTEL"
}
GET index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "TYPE": "AIRPORT"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```